# Replacing data on some condition in RDDs and filtering out non required RDDs

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I've RDD which looks like this:

```
[((String, String, String), (String, String))]
```

Sample data is like this:

```
((10,1,a),(x,3))
((10,2,b),(y,5))
((11,2,b),
((11,3,c),(z,4))
```

So if the value of 2nd string inside key is 2 or 3, replace it with 2-3, if it is 1 or if the rdd is like the 3rd one, remove that rdd.

So the expected output is like this:

```
((10,2-3,b),(y,5))
((11,2-3,c),(z,4))
```

Comment: What have you tried till now? It looks like a `map` with a set of case statements might be of some help to you

Comment: Also, if you have data like the third row then your RDD is not of type `[((String, String, String), (String, String))]`

Comment: I don't know how to proceed with it..am new to this. Can you help me with the case statements of map you're talking about?

Comment: Also that 3rd row case is something which I found in my data which could be some wrong data and hence I wanted to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

Given a input data as

```
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
  (("10","1","a"),("x","3")),
  (("10","2","b"),("y","5")),
  (("11","2","b"),()),
  (("11","3","c"),("z","4"))
))
```

You can do the following to get your desired output as

```
rdd.filter(x => x._1._2 != "1").filter(x => x._2 != ()).map(x => {
  if(x._1._2 == "2" || x._1._2 == "3") ((x._1._1, "2-3", x._1._3), x._2)
  else ((x._1._1, x._1._2, x._1._3), x._2)
})
```

Your output would be

```
((10,2-3,b),(y,5))
((11,2-3,c),(z,4))
```

Thanks to philantrovert for pointing out that it has to be `String` rather than an `Int`.

Comment: The `rdd` you have used is of type `RDD[((Int, Int, String), Any)]`. I'm still unclear how does OP has an RDD of type `RDD[((Int, String, String), (String, Int))]` when his data is like how it is represented in the question.

Comment: yeah you are right @philantrovert. may be there are string on the second tuple and he just wants to filter them out. Or may be he just guessed it.

Comment: The solution that u provided worked for me for replacing the data but rdds wit string value 1 _1._1 are still there and aren't filtered out..please help

Comment: what do you mean `rdds wit string value 1 _1._1 are still there and aren't filtered out`? can you give an example?

Comment: Ok so the 1st row is still coming apart from the expected output. The first row was supposed to be removed as there was 1 at  _1._1

Comment: _1._1 is 10 or 11 but _1._2 is 1 or 2 or 3 . I think you are missing something.

Comment: Sorry..I meant _1._2 only

Comment: I have update my answer :) @philantrovert had already point out that I was using Int instead of String. Thanks philantrovert